# Is there anything wrong with "move(-1)" as an AngularJS expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting this error: `[$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: move(`

From this code: `<button type="button" ng-click="move(-1)" tabindex="-1">`

Is there something syntactically wrong with `move(-1)` in AngularJS?

Side note: I seem to have errors cropping up anywhere I have a minus sign in an Angular expression. For example: `<span data-ng-click=" order('-name') " data-ng-class="{active: column == '-name'}">` is throwing a different error: `Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 6-7 ['] in expression [order(']`.

From everything I've read, these don't seem like syntax errors to me. Is there something else going on here?

Comment: it's not an actual negative interger, why are you using -?

Comment: I think the first example comes from `ui-bootstrap`. In the `order` method I'm using it to denote descending order.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a fiddle/plunker?

Comment: Just tested `<button type="button" ng-click="test(-1)">Test</button>` and in my controller `$scope.test = function (val) { $log.debug('val', val); };` and this works 100% in AngularJS v1.3.15. So must be something else going on there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same thing. Check to make sure that it isn't one of your Chrome extensions that is causing the problem. I disabled Batarang specifically and the error went away.

Comment: After seeing this answer, I felt like an idiot spending 2 hrs on this error. I did not know Batarang could create this error :/
Thanks a lot for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same problem and spent a few hours in it, but no luck. But hopefully my findings would be helpful.

The "bug" only happens on my main chrome windows, doesn't happen on incognito window, FF and IE.

In my case I tried to use: `ng-click="changeScore(data.game.home, -1)"`, it reports ueoe. Tried to change to other arguments, but it doesn't work as long as it contains a dash:

```
changeScore(-1)
changeScore('-1')
changeScore('abc-efg')
```

When I step through angular.js, it seems like it has successfully parsed `changeScore(data.game.home, -1)` and then try to parse `changeScore(data` again, which is an incomplete statement, resulting error. But unfortunately I can't tell what has triggered the re-parse and can't reproduce it in jsfiddle.