# AngularJS syntax error on expression when using add/subtract operators

Tags: angularjs

I have an element as below :

```
<a class="previous i-previous  fa fa-caret-left" href=""
    ng-click="setPage(currentPage-1)"
    ng-hide="currentPage == 0">
</a>
```

I had this code working but now I have this exception :

> Error: [$parse:syntax]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B)%5D&p2=null&p3=setPage(currentPage&p4=setPage(currentPage

The code that causes the exception is :

```
ng-click="setPage(currentPage-1)"
```

When i removed `-1` it works so it seems the problem is about that part.

What might be the cause of this exception?

EDIT :

I have this code in my controller :

```
$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.setPage = function (page) { 
        $scope.currentPage = page;
    };
```

Comment: try `setPage(--currentPage)`

Comment: It's running correctly.
 http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/16666/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by batarang in Chrome, disable it or use other browser to test, or use incognito mode.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31006278/5039495

Comment: What do you want to say ?

Comment: Wow, it caused me for 2 hours. Thanks.

Comment: @Vineet setPage(currentPage-1) is valid angular syntax, but it get parsed incorrectly on chrome with batarang. You can call it a false positive.

Comment: @cuneytyvz Yea I spent few hours on it as well, hope they will fix it soon

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
ng-click="currentPage = currentPage - 1; setPage(currentPage)"
```

Comment: I have this method in other parts of my code and use it for pagination view like "currentpage + 1" also. I'm going to try this but i think "currentPage-1" is also needs to be working.

Comment: great thanks, it worked. But i still didn't get why the other one does not.

Comment: Simply, your `ng-click` function sends the value first to controller and then decreasing it by 1.

Comment: i mean i didn't get why the version in the question does not work. And also currentPage-- also didn't work but 'ng-click="currentPage = currentPage - 1; setPage(currentPage)"' did work.

Answer (score 0):

It's running correctly. check fiddle

```
<div ng-app>

  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <a  href=""
    ng-click="setPage(currentPage-1)"
    ng-hide="currentPage == 0">test
</a>
  </div>
</div>



function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.currentPage = 5;
$scope.setPage = function (page) { 
        $scope.currentPage = page;
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/16666/